# Is there a way to browse and sort structure elements in C with for loop in a descending order?

Tags: c, struct

I'd like to sort a structure of 24 different elements in a descending order. But I don't know if there is a way to do it without using pointers and tables under the structure. I want to do it just with storing different elements and after that I will browse all my element with a for loop and sorting them in a descending order !!

Here is my program, my variable name's are in French. In my header file I declare this :

```
#define SEUIL 5

typedef struct BEO_acc BEO_acc;

// first structure to receive my element and affect them to my variables 
struct BEO_acc {
    int Energie;
    int Kilometrage;
    int date;
};

typedef struct Historique_BEO_acc Historique_BEO_acc;

// second structure where I want to store all my max values of energy given by the user 
struct Historique_BEO_acc {
    int energie1;
    int kilomtrage1;
    int date1;
    int energie2;
    int kilomtrage2;
    int date2;
    int energie3;
    int kilomtrage3;
    int date3;
    int energie4;
    int kilomtrage4;
    int date4;
    int energie5;
    int kilomtrage5;
    int date5;
    int energie6;
    int kilomtrage6;
    int date6;
    int energie7;
    int kilomtrage7;
    int date7;
    int energie8;
    int kilomtrage8;
    int date8;
 };

int FUN_beo_acc(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3);
```

And here is my cpp program :

```
#include "prototype_beo.h";
#include <stdio.h>;
#define SEUIL 5
#define RESET_VALUE 0


int FUN_beo_acc(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
BEO_acc accumulateur;
accumulateur.Energie = arg1;
accumulateur.Kilometrage = arg2;
accumulateur.date = arg3;


return accumulateur.Energie;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
BEO_acc accumulateur = {RESET_VALUE, RESET_VALUE, RESET_VALUE};
Historique_BEO_acc Historique = {RESET_VALUE, RESET_VALUE, 
RESET_VALUE, RESET_VALUE, RESET_VALUE, RESET_VALUE, 
RESET_VALUE, RESET_VALUE, RESET_VALUE};
int seuil = SEUIL;
int returned_arg;
int v1, v2, v3;



printf("introduire le premier argument de la fonction \n");
scanf("%d", &v1);
printf("introduire la valeur du deuxième argument ");
scanf("%d", &v2);
printf("introduire la valeur du troisième argument ");
scanf("%d", &v3);
returned_arg = FUN_beo_acc(v1, v2, v3);

while(returned_arg < seuil)
{
printf("introduire le premier argument de la fonction \n");
scanf("%d", &v1);
printf("introduire la valeur du deuxième argument ");
scanf("%d", &v2);
printf("introduire la valeur du troisième argument ");
scanf("%d", &v3);
returned_arg = FUN_beo_acc(v1, v2, v3); 
}

if (returned_arg > seuil)
{
    accumulateur.Energie = returned_arg;
    accumulateur.Kilometrage = v2+10;
    accumulateur.date = v3+10;

    printf("l''energie max est de : %d ", 
    accumulateur.Energie);
    printf("la distance est de : %d ", 
    accumulateur.Kilometrage);
    printf("la date  est de : %d ", accumulateur.date);
    }
    }
```

for the moment I just did some entring values and I store them in the first structure. I want at each time that my energy is greater to 5 I will store it in the great stucture. at the end of my storing I will sort my  great structure and I will place the values in a descending order of energy.

Comment: you can implement your version of any [sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) or use the ready-made `qsort()` function where you don't even need a single loop.

Comment: I wanted to use qsort () function , but what I wanted is to access my structure element in real time and change them by a simple algorithme

Comment: You want to keep your data in order while entering values? I mean, just after your program gets the 2nd element it decides to put it before or after the 1st? Consider using a linked list or a binary tree if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not use "big structure" to store the data only table of the "small structures". Then you can easly sort it as you need.
Example:

```
typedef struct {
int  Energie;
int  Kilometrage;
int date;
}BEO_acc;



int compare(const void *elem1, const void *elem2)  //energy is always positive :)
{
    return ((BEO_acc *)elem1) -> Energie - ((BEO_acc *)elem2)  -> Energie;
}


BEO_acc *histData = NULL;



int main()
{
    int count  = 30;
    size_t nrecords = 0;
    BEO_acc acc;
    while(count--)
    {
        acc.Energie = rand() % 500;
        if(acc.Energie > 300)
        {
            BEO_acc *tmp = realloc(histData, (nrecords + 1) * sizeof(acc));
            if(tmp)
            {
                histData = tmp;
                histData[nrecords++] = acc;
            }
            else
            {
                //error actions
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nBefore qsort:\n");
    for(size_t index = 0; index < nrecords; index++)
    {
        printf("%05zu - %d\n", index, histData[index].Energie);
    }
    qsort(histData, nrecords, sizeof(*histData), compare);
    printf("\nAftrer qsort:\n");
    for(size_t index = 0; index < nrecords; index++)
    {
        printf("%05zu - %d\n", index, histData[index].Energie);
    }
}
```

You can play with it yourself: https://onlinegdb.com/rJ-fdGqHoB

Comment: I will take inspiration in your programm to store the other data. I will come back if I have some requierements

Answer (score 0):

When you find yourself creating objects with names like `thing1`, `thing2`, `thing3`, that’s a strong hint that you want to be using an *array*.

I would suggest you redefine `struct Historique_BEO_acc` as an *array* of `struct BEO_acc`:

```
struct BEO_acc Historique_BEO_acc[N]; // where N is the number of elements you want to store
```

You would write to each element as

```
Historique_BEO_acc[i].Energie = ...;
Historique_BEO_acc[i].Kilomitrage = ...;
Historique_BEO_acc[i].date = ...;
```

You could then use the `qsort()` library function to sort the array.  You just need to write a comparison function to tell `qsort()` how to order the elements.  If you want to sort by `Energie` in descending order, your function would look something like

```
int cmp_beo( const void *l, const void *r )
{
  const struct BEO_acc *ll = l;
  const struct BEO_acc *lr = r;

  if ( ll->Energie < lr->Energie )
    return 1;
  else if ( ll->Energie > lr->Energie )
    return -1;
  else 
    return 0;
}
```

then you’d call `qsort()` as

```
qsort( Historique_BEO_acc, N, sizeof Historique_BEO_acc, cmp_beo);
```

Comment: Yes, I get it. But what I wont is to avoid the use of the qsort() function. I will try also this way by avoiding it.

Answer (score 0):

After some reflexion I think that we can do it with the way below, without using pointers or qsort function :

```
BEO_acc accumulateur = {RESET_VALUE, RESET_VALUE, RESET_VALUE};
BEO_acc hist_BEO[TAILLE_MEMOIRE_REQUISE] = {accumulateur,accumulateur,accumulateur, 
{9,6,5},accumulateur,accumulateur,accumulateur,accumulateur};
int x = 0, xx = 0, xxx = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<TAILLE_MEMOIRE_REQUISE;j++)
{
    for (int i=0; i< TAILLE_MEMOIRE_REQUISE; i++)
    {
        if(hist_BEO[i].Energie>hist_BEO[i+1].Energie)
            {
                x = hist_BEO[i+1].Energie;
                xx = hist_BEO[i+1].Kilometrage;
                xxx = hist_BEO[i+1].date;

                hist_BEO[i+1].Energie = hist_BEO[i].Energie;
                hist_BEO[i+1].Kilometrage = hist_BEO[i].Kilometrage;
                hist_BEO[i+1].date = hist_BEO[i].date;

                hist_BEO[i].Energie = x;
                hist_BEO[i].Kilometrage = xx;
                hist_BEO[i].date = xxx;

                x = 0;
                xx = 0;
                xxx = 0;
            }
           }
           }
```

And thankyou for suggestions.